# How to get proto message leaf data in C++ if we only know the leaf paths?

Tags: c++, reflection, iteration, protocol-buffers

I have some paths, such as "data.user.user_id"、"data.user.name" etc.
And some messages, maybe proto like:

```
message xxx {
    Data data = 0;
}
message Data {
    User user = 0;
}
message User {
    int64 user_id = 0;
    string name = 1;
}
```

I iterate the message by reflection, collect all paths including repeated fields and map to get the data. The protobuf reflection(c++) provides `ListFields` which only gets children, without grandchildren etc. It can not get the leaf field! So I have to do the iterative job.

The iteration is very tedious. And I worry about bugs.

I had read the protobuf reflection code and not found a good method to get the leaf data in this condition. Does anyone know some better ways to do this? Are there some libraries for this condition?